# Pass to MsgBox only some variables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple Access Module which checks if a file already exists or not on a specified folder, and if it doesn't exists it attributes 1 to it. So far so good. What I would like to know if it's possible on a MessageBox to pass only the missing file names.

For example:

```
If Len(FilePath & FileName) = 0 Then
  FileName = 1
Else
  FileName = 0
If Len(FilePath & FileName2) = 0 Then
  FileName2 = 1
Else
  FileName2 = 0
If Len(FilePath & FileName3) = 0 Then
  FileName3 = 1
Else
  FileName3 = 0
End If
End If
End If

MsgBox "The Following files are missing:" & vbNewLine....
```

And here is where i'm stuck. I would like that after the above phrase to pass only the FileNames which have 1 assigned to it, pretty much like if in SQL we applied a "Where Like 1" clause.

Thanks for any help,
Vítor

Comment: `So far so good` ... not at all. I'm afraid you'll have to go back a step and start reading a book or tutorial about VBA. There's not much others can (or should) do for you until you know the basics of using variables, loops and such.

Comment: Indeed. I'm way off of what i should do. Will have to read it again. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your `MsgBox` code comes around, your "FileName" variable values have been lost and set to either 1 or 0, so you can't at that point in time, say which files are "1", even if you tested them again at this point.

Instead though, you could have a new variable, lets call it `listOfFiles`, that you add to in your `if` statements like:

```
If Len(FilePath & FileName) = 0 Then
    FileName = 1
    listOfFiles = listOfFiles & vbCRLF & FileName
Else
    FileName = 0
    If Len(FilePath & FileName2) = 0 Then
        FileName2 = 1
        listOfFiles = listOfFiles & vbCRLF & FileName2
    Else
        FileName2 = 0
        If Len(FilePath & FileName3) = 0 Then
          FileName3 = 1
          listOfFiles = listOfFiles & vbCRLF & FileName3
        Else
          FileName3 = 0
        End If
    End If
End If

MsgBox "The Following files are missing:" & listOfFiles
```

Comment: Thanks! But i clearly need to revise all of this again as i am way off of the pretended result. Thanks for the feedback. :)